# Creating preview page before submit data into database

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to create preview page i.e let us consider a registration form and before submit data to database user should see preview of data what they entered. i am using Spring mvc 3.0 and hibernate

=> this is my controller method, after submit it is going to database and inserting data and i am displaying that data on grid

```
@RequestMapping( value="/catalogue/create.action", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView create(@ModelAttribute CatalogueBase catalogueForm) throws Exception {  

        ModelAndView mvc = null;
        try{

            List<CatalogueBase> catalogueBases =  new ArrayList<CatalogueBase>(); //getCatalogueBase(request);
            catalogueBases.add(catalogueForm);
            List<CatalogueBase> catalogueBaseList = catalogueService.create(catalogueBases);
            mvc =   new ModelAndView("catalogue/catalogueList");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mvc;
    }
```

=> now i kept one method it goes to preview page  and if data is ok then it go to above method to insert into database

```
@RequestMapping( value="/catalogue/FormPreview.action", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command) throws Exception {

            CatalogueBase catalogueBase = new CatalogueBase();

                // hear i setting only one value 

            request.setAttribute("titleNo", catalogueBase.getTitleNumber());

            return new ModelAndView("catalogue/catalogueFormPreview","catalogueBase",catalogueBase);

        }
```

and in jsp i gave EL like this   ===== > ${catalogueBase.titleNo}

but it is getting null values

thanks in advance

Comment: What does "but it is getting null values" exactly mean? A NullPointerException or getting an null titleNo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set as

```
request.setAttribute("titleNo", catalogueBase.getTitleNumber());
```

you should access this variable on the page as `${titleNo}`.

And according to your 2nd method it should be null because you create new object `new CatalogueBase()`.